# Not able to hit api to verify otp ( Used Volley)

Tags: android, android-volley, one-time-password

i am giving the link to the query i have raised on github respository of AndroidHive please take a look
my issue- https://github.com/rajatbeck/LoginWithOTP/issues/1
i made some changes like i am registering with single parameter i.e. phone number
Original code - http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-2/